# How do I install hgview on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial

I'm trying to install `hgview` on Ubuntu, but it's not working.

```
$ hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.1)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2012 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ sudo apt-get install hgview
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  hgview: Depends: mercurial (>= 0.9.3)
E: Broken packages
```

Mercurial *is* installed from the Ubuntu repository.  As for `dpkg`, I get:

```
$ dpkg -l mercurial*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                           Version                                        Description
+++-==============================================-==============================================-============================================================================================================
ii  mercurial                                      2.1-0ppa1~lucid1                               easy-to-use, scalable distributed version control system
ii  mercurial-common                               2.1-0ppa1~lucid1                               easy-to-use, scalable distributed version control system (common files)
ii  mercurial-git                                  0.3.1-1~lucid1                                 Git plugin for Mercurial
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Can you list your package sources and do a "dpkg -l mercurial*"?

Comment: are you sure that hg was installed from the Ubuntu repositories?  doing an "aptitude search mercurial" will show an 'i' in left hand column if hg is installed via the repos.  Also, "which hg" should give a path that's within /usr/bin or similar, not /usr/local or elsewhere.

Comment: Verified, and added that information into the question.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? I want to try to replicate it.

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using tortoisehg?

Comment: @Gert This should be 10.04 (from the output of dpkg -> lucid)